# Kohana 3.2 request->headers['Content-Type'] keeps failing

Tags: php, header, kohana, content-type, kohana-3

This won't work in Kohana 3.2 for some reason:

```
$this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml';
```

Has this changed since Kohana 3.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not work in 3.1 either, but this should:

```
$this->request->headers('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

See http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#headers
This was one of the Request/Response refactoring changes from 3.1.

Comment: I was upgrading from a 3.0 app...  Thanks! Should I update the question to reflect 3.1?

Comment: I believe you need to use the response object in 3.2? $this->response->headers('Content-Type', 'text/xml');